# How to style ::selection pseudo element in a styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, pseudo-element, css-in-js

I want to do that with a styled component:

```css
.jTHnFZ ::selection {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

I write this styled component:

```js
const MyDiv = styled.div`
    ::selection {
        background-color: pink;
    }
`
```

But the result is:

```css
.jTHnFZ::selection {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

The result is the same with this styled component:

```js
const MyDiv = styled.div`
    & ::selection {
        background-color: pink;
    }
`
```

The only way I found to attibute a color to the `::selection` pseudo element is to do this:

```js
const MyDiv = styled.div`
    *::selection {
        background-color: pink;
    }
`
```

And the result is then:

```css
.jTHnFZ *::selection {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

It works but is there a better way to do it, avoiding the `*`?

Comment: What is `.jTHnFZ`?

Comment: `.jTHnFZ` is the class generate by my styled component

Comment: I don't understand. can you show your code completely? I and others can help better.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

My project is large and contains a lot of files, so I have simplified this code [in this repository](https://github.com/centvingt/nested-pseudo-element-in-styled-component).

But in this repository `& ::selection {...}` works fine (this nested pseudo element is in [this file](https://github.com/centvingt/nested-pseudo-element-in-styled-component/blob/main/elements/MyDiv.jsx)).

Comment: So the problem is not with the styled components but with my project, [here is its repository](https://github.com/centvingt/nested-pseudo-element-in-styled-component-doesnt-work). The file with the problematic nested pseudo element [is here](https://github.com/centvingt/nested-pseudo-element-in-styled-component-doesnt-work/blob/main/elements/LayoutElements.jsx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Please remove space after `&`:

```
const MyDiv = styled.div`
    &::selection {
        background-color: pink;
    }
`
```

**Note to:** https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/nz8gt9/using_the_selection_css_attribute_using_styled/

Comment: `&::selection` selects the `div` itself, whereas i want to select the descendants of that `div`

Comment: In fact, the correct selector to select descendants of  the `div` is `& ::selection` (with a space between `&` and `::selection`). It works fine when I try this in a new project but it doesn't work in my current project

Comment: @VincentCaronnet Tried this?: `& > ::selection`

Comment: The CSS selector `& > ::selection` would select only direct children whereas I want to select all descendants. The right syntax to do that is `& ::selection` but it doesn't work in my project

Comment: @VincentCaronnet Why not use `& *::selection`?  you said `It works but is there a better way to do it, avoiding the *?`

Comment: I'm suspicious of the universal selector which might have performance issues. But it seems that in reality this performance impact is negligible, so I'm going to stick with the universal selector.